# Redux immutable change array order

Tags: redux, immutable.js

So I'm trying to change the order of an array using redux and immutable. What I'm basically doing is grabbing the current array, modifying it, and updating the state with modified copy, like so:

```
case MOVE_LAYOUT: {
    const index = action.payload;
    const lower = index - 1;
    const element = state.getIn(['someArray', index]);
    if (action.direction === 'up') {
        const arr = state.get('someArray');
        const newArr = arr.splice(lower, 0, element);
        const remove = newArr.splice(index, 1);
        return state.set('someArray', remove);
    }
    return false;
}
```

For the sake of the question, let's assume `action.payload` is passed properly, and that a `console.log(remove.toJS())` will return what I want. However, when I update `someArray` nothing happens. Why would this be?

Answer (score 0):

So here's the answer:

```
case MOVE_LAYOUT: {
    const index = action.payload;
    const arr = state.get('someArray').toJS();
    let next;
    if (action.direction === 'up') {
        next = index - 1;
    } else {
        next = index + 1;
    }
    const temp = arr[index];
    arr[index] = arr[next];
    arr[next] = temp;
    return state.set('someArray', fromJS(arr));
}
```

Basically, I'll make a copy of the array, and modify the index (move by 1 up or 1 down), and set the modified array copy back to state. Problem with initial approach was not using `.toJS()` and `.fromJS()`, so the results were immutable list, rather than JS object.